# How to toggle androidx.SearchView search icon to back arrow

Tags: android, androidx, searchview

I want to toggle button search with search icon to a back button with a back functionality and icon.

I am using androidx searchView without a ToolBar to fulfill a product requirement, so OptionsMenu solutions are not applicable in my case

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/simpleSearchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/search_bar_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
            android:queryBackground="@null"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            app:searchIcon="@drawable/icon_search"
            app:defaultQueryHint="@string/search" />
```

Tried to change them through an XML selector but the icon disappears when the SearchView is focused

here is my selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_search" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_search" android:state_focused="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_back" />
</selector>
```

Also read the documents [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SearchView) couldn't find a utility function to support my use case

this is the image to when the SearchView is Focused and active, replace search with back button [image]

Comment: can you share your requirement screenshot?

Comment: added an image, SearchView doesn't belong to the parent fragment that has the toolbar, it's a child fragment for a ViewPager